# how to add two column from different tables in report in access

Tags: database, ms-access

i made a table called cafe_income

```
ItemID |ItemName| PriceOfUnit  | NumberOfSold | Total   
  1    |  tea   |       3      |       6      |   18
```

and another table called market_income

```
ItemID | ItemName  | PriceOfUnit  | NumberOfSold | Total 
   1   | chocolate |       2      |       3      |   6
```

in both cases total = PriceOfUnit  * NumberOfSold

when i add both of total columns in a report it does not display all the items, it only displays items depending on the less number of items in all the tables

i need to display all sold items from the two tables and if one of them larger than other it can display 0 instead of removing the items to make both of two tables the same size.

Comment: Can you post your SQL? Is there any relationship between the two tables? Doesn't look like it, so possibly you want a union query?

Comment: Instead of deriving the report from a table, create a view (query) which union's the results of both tables together and then base the report on the view.  My rule of thumb is use queries to build data the way I need it, use reports to make it look pretty; and seldom build on the tables directly.  I never know when i may want to join something in later; and changing a query is easier later that way.

Comment: Just to be clear, you only want the total for "tea" to show up in the example above because for item id 1, 18 > 6?  Even though one item 1 is tea and the other is chocolate?

Comment: in the first table if i sold tea , water and cola, and from the market ' second table ' i sold chocolate,lays , Doritos and banana.
i need query or report or any thing displays the total for two tables 
some thing like that " total in cafe = 50 " , "total in market = 70"